# Reduced row-echelon form, and $A^{-1}B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to prove the following

Let $A$ be a nonsingular $n \times n$ matrix and let $B$ be an $n \times r$ matrix. Show that the reduced row echelon form of $(A|B)$ is $(I|C)$, where $C=A^{-1} B$

Since $A$ is nonsingular $A*A^{-1} = I $
And if you multiply $A^{-1}$ with $B$ you get $A^{-1} B$, which is $C$
But I'm not sure if you're allowed to say $(A|B)*A^{-1} = (I|C)$

All in all, I'm quite sure this is not the right/a good proof. (I didn't incorporate that this is all about reduced row echelon forms)

If anyone can help me I'd appreciate it a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is nonsingular, Gaussian elimination will find a pivot in each column. Backwards elimination will get the reduced row echelon form, which is the identity.

Thus, the elementary matrices that give the RREF multiply to yield $A^{-1}$.

If $b$ is any column vector, the same Gaussian elimination steps as before on the matrix $[A\mid b]$ will produce the matrix $[I\mid c]$, where $c=A^{-1}b$, because we're essentially solving the linear system $Ax=b$.

So, if $B=[b_1\;b_2\;\dots\;b_r]$, Gaussian elimination will produce
$$
[A\mid B]=[A\mid b_1\;b_2\;\dots\;b_r]\to 
[I\mid A^{-1}b_1\;A^{-1}b_2\;\dots\;A^{-1}b_r]=
[I\mid A^{-1}B]
$$